# Select count with 0 count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have following query:

```
SELECT top (5) CAST(Created AS DATE) as DateField, 
  Count(id) as Counted
FROM Table
GROUP BY CAST(Created AS DATE)
order by DateField desc
```

Lets say it will return following data set

```
DateField   Counted
2016-01-18  34
2016-01-17  99
2016-01-14  1
2015-12-28  1
2015-12-27  6
```

But when I have Counted = 0 for certain Date I would like to get that in result set. So for example it should look like following

```
DateField   Counted
2016-01-18  34
2016-01-17  99
2016-01-16  0
2016-01-15  0
2016-01-14  1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Think about this for a second....if the count is 0 that means there are no rows returned. With no rows you can't get a return. What you could do instead is use another table (like a tally table) as the basis of your query with a left join to your count logic. That way you would still get a row when there is no data for that date. Make sense?

Comment: use a numbers table to generate all the necessary dates, then left join your query onto that.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon KM's answer, you need a date table which is like a numbers table.
There are many examples on the web but here's a simple one.

```
CREATE TABLE DateList (
 DateValue DATE,
 CONSTRAINT PK_DateList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DateValue)
 )
 GO
 -- Insert dates from 01/01/2015 and 12/31/2015
 DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '01/01/2015'
 DECLARE @EndDatePlus1 DATE = '01/01/2016'
 DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = @StartDate

 WHILE @EndDatePlus1 > @CurrentDate
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DateList VALUES (@CurrentDate)
    SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@CurrentDate)
    END
```

Now you have a table

[image]

then you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT top (5)  DateValue, isnull(Count(id),0) as Counted
FROM DateList 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table
  on DateValue = CAST(Created AS DATE) 
GROUP BY DateValue
order by DateValue desc
```

Two notes:
You'll need a where clause to specify your range.
A join on a cast isn't ideal. The type in your date table should match the type in your regular table.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution as a single query:

```
;WITH dates AS 
(
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1, '2016-01-14') as date) 'date' 
  FROM sys.all_objects
) 
SELECT TOP 5 
      [date] AS 'DateField', 
      SUM(CASE WHEN Created IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'Counted'
  FROM dates
  LEFT JOIN Table ON [date]=CAST(Created  as date)
GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date]
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using system tables to generate rows

Comment: We just need a sequence of numbers (or dates). You can use a temporary table as in the answer below or generate a sequence from row numbers using any table or view with a lot of rows. View sys.all_objects is good enought for that purpose but you can use your own table, f.e. `SELECT TOP 1000 CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created) -1 ,'2016-01-14') as date) 'date' FROM Table`

Answer (score 1):

For a more edgy solution, you could use a recursive common table expression to create the date list. PLEASE NOTE: do not use recursive common table expressions in your day job! They are dangerous because it is easy to create one that never terminates.

```
    DECLARE @StartDate date = '1/1/2016';
    DECLARE @EndDate date = '1/15/2016';

    WITH DateList(DateValue)
    AS
    (
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateValue)
            FROM DateList
            WHERE DateList.DateValue < @EndDate
    )
    SELECT DateValue, isnull(Count(id),0) as Counted
    FROM DateList 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table]
      ON DateValue = CAST(Created AS DATE) 
    GROUP BY DateValue
    ORDER BY DateValue DESC
```