# Assistance with LEFT JOIN.

Tags: sql-server, select, ssms, case-when

Trying to get a null value when the count = 0. Below is the code that I using to count the number of sites that fit a certain criteria. In this case, code beginning with 11 or 21. There is a question of similar construct but it seems as if mine is of a simpler nature.

```
 SELECT
 [Area],
 COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
 FROM
 dbo.sizeclassreport
 Where area='000005' and (code like '11%' or code like '21%')
 GROUP BY
 [area]
 UNION ALL
```

So from responses, it seems as if I need to construct an additional table (tally table as the other question says) that lists the areas then do a left join. Below is my first attempt at this.

```
 Create TABLE areas
 (
 Area char(6), NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT PK_AREAS PRIMARY KEY (areas)

 Select * from areas
 LEFT JOIN dbo.sizeclassreport ON areas.areas = area.sizeclassreport
 COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
 FROM
 dbo.sizeclassreport
 Where area='000005' and (code like '11%' or code like '21%')
 GROUP BY
 [area]
 UNION ALL
```

Comment: You'll never get 0 because there are no rows to count. You need to left join your query with a table that lists all the areas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select count with 0 count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934538/select-count-with-0-count)

Comment: The answer below works but I am designing this for someone else and who will want a single result not 11 in this case. So, about this left join. First, i construct a table with all of my areas (17 in this case). Is it ok that this table only has one column.

Comment: `GROUP BY [area]` means to return 1 row for each area.

Comment: Looking at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp.
So, would it look something like this:
     SELECT column_name(s)
     FROM table1
     LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
     COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
     FROM
     dbo.sizeclassreport
     Where area='000005' and (code like '11%' or code like '21%')
     GROUP BY
 [area]

Comment: I didn't see that you had `WHERE area = '00005'`. You don't need `GROUP BY [area]` if you're just selecting for a single area.

Comment: I have since edited the question.

Comment: You don't need a new table for this, you can use a subquery or CTE. And if you're just selecting a single area, you can do it as in the answer that you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no data you don't get a row to present the zero against. You can force a row to exist however, then if data exists it will be presented, if not you get zero via the `coalesce()` function.

```
SELECT
       '000005' as area
     , COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.sizeclassreport 
           WHERE area = '000005' AND code LIKE '11%' OR code LIKE '21%'), 0)
```